# Understanding Structure Definition and Implementation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration, typedef

Help me understand these struct implementations. I am confused. I am aware of the 1st implementation. The second one is confusing me. Thanks for your help guys

1.

```
typedef struct
{
  int v;
  int w;
} Edge;

Edge EDGE(int, int);
```

2. 

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
Graph GRAPHinit(int);
```

This graph type is confusing me.

Comment: There is no definition in the second snippet, it only declares a type alias for a pointer to `struct graph` plus a function that returns such a pointer

Comment: 2) is confusing you because hiding pointers behind a typedef is one of those very bad ideas that should never be done. Other than that, it doesn't actually declare the struct, you need a `struct graph` somewhere else for the code to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

In this typedef declaration:

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

there is introduces the incomplete structure type `struct graph` and for the  pointer to objects of the structure type `struct graph *`  there is introduced the alias (typedef) name `Graph`.

That is you may declare a variable of the pointer type like:

```
struct graph *p;
```

or:

```
Graph p;
```

So this function declaration:

```
Graph GRAPHinit(int);
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct graph * GRAPHinit(int);
```

Pay attention to that the type `struct graph` is incomplete type. So you may not define an object of the structure type until you will  provide the structure definition. On the other hand, pointers themselves are always complete types. So you may define an object of the pointer type `struct graph *` or that is the same `Graph`.

Where is such a typedef declaration is used?

For example imagine that you have a header file where there is the function declaration:

```
Graph GRAPHinit(int);
```

To make the declaration valid you need to sat the compiler what the name Graph means.

So before the function declaration in the header you will write:

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
Graph GRAPHinit(int);
```

It is enough to make this header syntactically and semantically correct.

The complete structure declaration can be a very big as for example:

```
struct graph
{
   T1 data_member_1;
   //...
   Tn data_member_n;
};

typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

But to declare the function in the header above this complete structure declaration is not required. So in the header there is used only this typedef:

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

that introduces all required types to make the function declaration

```
Graph GRAPHinit(int);
```

correct.

To make this typedef declaration:

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

more clear consider this typedef declaration

```
typedef int *Ptr;
```

It introduces the pointer typedef name Ptr as an alias for the pointer type `int *`. But the type specifier `int` is a fundamental type. It is known for the compiler.  As for the type specifier struct graph then it is a user-defined type specifier. So this typedef declaration:

```
typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

introduces the new (incomplete) type specifier struct graph and also an alias for the pointer type `struct graph *` named like `Graph`.

Comment: Is there a justifiable reason to cause this kind of pain when coding. I mean is there benefits of using such complicated struct declaration instead of straight forward implementation?

Comment: @Calvince It is only at first glance the typedef declaration looks complicated. For example a translation unit does not need the complete type of the structure.  It deals only with objects of the pointer type to the structure. So instead of always to write struct  graph * it is enough to write Graph throughout the translation unit.

Comment: What if the struct graph was to have member variables. Will this definition still stand?

Comment: @Calvince If the structure definition is not visible then you can not access its data members using an object of the pointer type typedef struct graph *Graph;. But for the function declaration this forward declaration of the structure in typedef is enough. If the function definition needs to access data members of an object of the structure type then you need of course to provide the structure definition.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
  typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

is to be read as

```
  typedef struct graph* Graph;
```

which means, `Graph` is a pointer of type `struct graph`.  The second statement then can be interpreted as

```
 struct graph * GRAPHinit(int);
```

which looks very much like a forward declaration of a function, accepting an `int` and returning a pointer to `struct graph`.

---

Note: While this usage is perfectly legal, it's confusing at best. never hide pointers behind a typedef, rather keep the type simple. Use it like

```
typedef struct graph myGraph;
myGraph* GRAPHinit(int);
```

Comment: To make it simple we can define a graph struct `struct graph{}` and later use it in the declaration as `struct graph *Graph`

Comment: Never hide pointers behind typedefs

Comment: @0___________ I was about to say that, thanks.

Comment: @O________ what  do you mean by "Never hide pointers behind typedefs"

Comment: @Calvince that, by seeing `Graph` as a type, you don't easily know whether it's an arithmetic/structure type or a pointer type.

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh thanks for the prompt response and explanation